# Python Regular Expression - check duplicate words

Tags: python

How can I check if the following sentence has duplicate words and identify which they are?
'Cherry tree blooming blooming will begin in in late April'
I used:
import re
check = re.search(r'(\b\w+)\s+\1', 'Cherry tree blooming blooming will begin in in later March, High Park Toronto')
print check.group(1)

It will only give me "blooming" but not the “in”.

Comment: Can you show your current coding attempt and explain what is currently not working?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work:

```
>>> text =  'Cherry tree blooming blooming will begin in in late April'.split()
>>> any(i for i in text if text.count(i) > 1)
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Using collections.Counter

```
>>> my_str = 'Cherry tree blooming blooming will begin in in late April'
>>> import collections
>>> collections.Counter(my_str.split()) # splits the string on whitespace and counts the word occurance.
Counter({'blooming': 2, 'in': 2, 'late': 1, 'begin': 1, 'Cherry': 1, 'tree': 1, 'will': 1, 'April': 1})
>>> any(x for x in collections.Counter(my_str.split()).values() if x>1)
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Define and use a function like the following:

```
def check_dup(sentence):
    words = sentence.split(" ")
    dup = {}

    for word in words:
        if word in dup.keys():
            return True
        dup[word] = "present"

    return False

print check_dup(sentence)
```

Answer (score 0):

Could use a set to keep track of the words you've seen previously:

```
sentence = 'Cherry tree blooming blooming will begin in in late April'
seen = set()

for word in sentence.split(' '):
    if word in seen:
        print(word)
    seen.add(word)
```